# When a rule parameter is set to an erroneous value, there's no error message when you click on "Activate"

Tags: sonarqube

[image]
On SonarQube 5.1, when a rule parameter is set to an erroneous value, there's no error message when you click on "Activate" and the rule does not get activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm the problem, [jira ticket](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6595) has been created. Thanks!